# How to fetch current user(Logged In user) details from particular collection in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

**Registration.dart**

In this code we have tried to register a user i.e. doctor details in the collection named 'doctor' and after registering it is navigating to login page(Login_Screen.dart). We are able to fetch and display current user name and email id ({user?.displayName},{user?.email}),but we are struggling to fetch other details of that user from collection 'doctor'.

```
child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Color(0xFF003058),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                    color: Colors.orange[700],
                    child: Text('Register',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        return;
                      } else {
                        await Doctors.add({
                          "name": _name,
                          "email": _email,
                          "license": _license,
                          "password": _password,
                          "cpassword": _cpassword,
                          "role":role
                        }).then((value) => print("Doctors details Added"));
                        try {
                          UserCredential user =
                              await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: _email, password: _password);
                          if (user != null) {
                            await auth.currentUser!
                                .updateProfile(displayName: _name);
                          }
                        } catch (e) {
                          print(e);
                        }
                      }
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()),
                      );
                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                    },
                  ),
```

**Login_Screen.dart**

```
child: RaisedButton(
                    textColor: Color(0xFF003058),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                    color: Colors.orange[700],
                    child: Text('Sign in',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                        return;
                      } else {
                        try {
                          final user = (await FirebaseAuth.instance
                                  .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email: emailController.text,
                            password:  passwordController.text,
                          ))
                              .user;
                          if (user != null) {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => App()),
                            );
                          }
                        } catch (e) {
                          print(e);
                        }
                      }
                      _formKey.currentState!.save();
                      print(emailController.text);
                      print( passwordController.text);
                    },
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on how you are storing the current user data in the collection,

if you are storing the current users data in a collection with location `"Users/userID"` where `userID` is the user's id , you can reach the user's data like:

```
await users.doc("Users/${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid}").get();
```

and in case you mean reaching the current logged in data in general, not the data that you store in a collection, you can do so simpley by calling:

- `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid` : to get the current user id (as we did above)
- `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.phoneNumber`: to get the current user's phone number.
- `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.displayName`: to get the current user's display name.
  and there are other kinds of data you can get.